# Orientation of Forge viewable generated on Design Automation in Forge Viewer not matching orientation in Inventor

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation, autodesk-inventor

I'm exporting SVFs from a model using the design automation API. With some models, the orientation in the Viewer of the viewable does not match the orientation in Inventor.
[image]

[image: In the viewer vs in Inventor]

How do I correct this so that all models come out with their Viewer orientation matching the input Inventor model?
The following code is where the SVF is exported. A blog post on this functionality would be helpful.

```cs
private string SaveForgeViewable(Inventor.Document doc) {
    string viewableOutputDir = null;
    using(new HeartBeat()) {
        //LogTrace($"** Saving SVF");
        try {
            TranslatorAddIn oAddin = null;

            foreach(ApplicationAddIn item in inventorApplication.ApplicationAddIns) {

                if (item.ClassIdString == "{C200B99B-B7DD-4114-A5E9-6557AB5ED8EC}") {
                    //Trace.TraceInformation("SVF Translator addin is available");
                    oAddin = (TranslatorAddIn) item;
                    break;
                }
                else {}
            }

            if (oAddin != null) {
                //Trace.TraceInformation("SVF Translator addin is available");
                TranslationContext oContext = inventorApplication.TransientObjects.CreateTranslationContext();
                // Setting context type
                oContext.Type = IOMechanismEnum.kFileBrowseIOMechanism;

                NameValueMap oOptions = inventorApplication.TransientObjects.CreateNameValueMap();
                // Create data medium;
                DataMedium oData = inventorApplication.TransientObjects.CreateDataMedium();

                Trace.TraceInformation("SVF save");
                var workingDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(doc.FullFileName);
                var sessionDir = Path.Combine(workingDir, "SvfOutput");

                // Make sure we delete any old contents that may be in the output directory first,
                // this is for local debugging. In DA4I the working directory is always clean
                if (Directory.Exists(sessionDir)) {
                    Directory.Delete(sessionDir, true);
                }

                oData.FileName = Path.Combine(sessionDir, "result.collaboration");
                var outputDir = Path.Combine(sessionDir, "output");
                var bubbleFileOriginal = Path.Combine(outputDir, "bubble.json");
                var bubbleFileNew = Path.Combine(sessionDir, "bubble.json");

                // Setup SVF options
                if (oAddin.get_HasSaveCopyAsOptions(doc, oContext, oOptions)) {
                    oOptions.set_Value("GeometryType", 1);
                    oOptions.set_Value("EnableExpressTranslation", true);
                    oOptions.set_Value("SVFFileOutputDir", sessionDir);
                    oOptions.set_Value("ExportFileProperties", false);
                    oOptions.set_Value("ObfuscateLabels", true);
                }

                oAddin.SaveCopyAs(doc, oContext, oOptions, oData);
                LogTrace($ "** Saved SVF as {oData.FileName}");
                File.Move(bubbleFileOriginal, bubbleFileNew);
                viewableOutputDir = sessionDir;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            LogError($ "********Export to format SVF failed: {e.Message}");
            return null;
        }
    }
    return viewableOutputDir;
}
```

Comment: I actually can't set the viewable to the right orientation and change the homescreen either - something seems off with the view cube. I click on a corner and it flips around into a rotated view of the orientation I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have met this issue too, this is our setup of SVF output which respects the ground of your design:

```
oOptions.set_Value("EnableExpressTranslation", false);
oOptions.set_Value("ExportFileProperties", true);
oOptions.set_Value("ObfuscateLabels", false);
```

For full code you can see our new sample app repository https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/forge-configurator-inventor/blob/master/AppBundles/CreateSVFPlugin/CreateSvfAutomation.cs#L96